# ROR: Search by Username and display their posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am learning Ruby on Rails and have a search form set up and its working. On the pins index view I can search for pins(posts) by their title. However if I wanted to search by Username which is not in the pins table and display the results on the Pins index page how would I do this? How do I access an attribute from a different table? (Sorry for the newbie attempt at explaining my issue)

**Pins controller**

```
 def index
    @pins = Pin.search(params[:term])
end
```

**Pin Model**

```
def self.search(term)
  if term
    where('description LIKE ?', "%#{term}%")
  else
     order('id DESC') 
  end
end
```

**_search.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag(pins_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', description: nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you share your database schema?

Comment: Could you update your code with full model/controller code? I'd like to know mainly if you use ActiveRecord or not, as it'll be easier to use its helper methods, rather than SQL queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have an association between `User` and `Pin`

```
class User
  has_many :pins
end

class Pin
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You can join `:user` from `Pin` and set conditions on the association:

```
Pin.joins(:user).where('users.username ? AND awesome = ?', 'Max', true)
# or the preferred method
Pin.joins(:user).where(user: { username: 'Max', awesome: true })
```

Note that we use `users.username` and not `user.username` when writing a SQL string you're specifying the table name - not the association.

To search for pins based on the username you could do:

```
def self.by_username(term)
  joins(:user).where('users.username LIKE ?', "%#{term}%")
end
```

Comment: On a side not - your controller should be deciding which scope on the model to use instead of having `if term` in your model.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set up something like

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pins

  # the username is stored in the attribute 'username'
end

class Pin < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

you may do the following

```
# PinsController
def index
  terms = params[:term]
  username = params[:username]

  @pins = Pin
  @pins = @pins.where("description LIKE '%?%'", term) if term
  @pins = @pins.includes(:user).where("users.username LIKE '%?%'", username) if username

  # you may want to sort by id anyway
  @pins = @pins.order('id DESC')  
end
```

Note that I put the code straight to the controller for brevity. You may refactor this to use your search method in pin model.

```
# _search.html.erb
<%= form_tag(pins_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term] %>
  <%= text_field_tag :username, params[:username] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', description: nil %>
<% end %>
```

In case you want to do some more searching and filtering you may have a look at the [ransack gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) although I think you're going the right path in trying to figure this out yourself.

Although those railscasts episodes are from the past I think they are applicable to the current rails versions. Anyway one can get the point from them

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Another good resource is gorails.com (not affiliate in any way!!). I can highly recommend them as a resource for learning

Comment: Thanks for the resources I will definitely check them out.